# getting 400 bad request on SOAP requests (Transfer-encoding: chunked problem?)

Tags: php, http, soap, http-headers, transfer-encoding

I have a situation like this.A SOAP request is sent from an application to our server.
The request works fine when testing locally but always fails when testing live on the dev server.
The administrator of that application sent me their request so I can test it and figure out what is wrong. So when I remove the Transfer-encoding: chunked header the response is fine (from Postman and SoapUI) but with the Transfer-encoding header present it fails.

Here is the request that is sent to our web service:

**request headers:**

```
POST http://*******/soap-mobile HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
SOAPAction:"http://********************************"
User-Agent: Apache CXF 2.4.6
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: *****************
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

**request body:**

`ff9 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns8:ZapisiVprasanjaZaUporabnika xmlns:ns2="http://*******" xmlns:ns4="http://***" xmlns:ns6="http://******" xmlns:ns7="http://******" xmlns:ns8="http://******" xmlns:ns9="http://******" xmlns:ns10="http://******" xmlns:ns11="http://*********"><input><ns6:vprasanjaZaUporabnika><ns10:vprasanjaZaVrstoPredmetaZavarovanja><ns10:vrstaPredmetaZavarovanja>avto</ns10:vrstaPredmetaZavarovanja><ns10:vprasanja><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25390</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>ŠTEVILKE</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>true</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Stanje števca (km)</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>STEVILO_JS</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448101</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P244</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25392</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>ZNAKI</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>false</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Lastnik vozila</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>SEZNAM</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448103</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P246</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:parameterLOVsDTO><ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:iidLov>498562</ns4:iidLov><ns4:iidParameter>448103</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:vrednost>1</ns4:vrednost><ns4:vrstniRed>1</ns4:vrstniRed><ns4:prikazanaVrednost>fizièna oseba</ns4:prikazanaVrednost><ns4:jezik>sl</ns4:jezik></ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:iidLov>498563</ns4:iidLov><ns4:iidParameter>448103</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:vrednost>2</ns4:vrednost><ns4:vrstniRed>2</ns4:vrstniRed><ns4:prikazanaVrednost>podjetje</ns4:prikazanaVrednost><ns4:jezik>sl</ns4:jezik></ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:iidLov>498564</ns4:iidLov><ns4:iidParameter>448103</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:vrednost>3</ns4:vrednost><ns4:vrstniRed>3</ns4:vrstniRed><ns4:prikazanaVrednost>lizing</ns4:prikazanaVrednost><ns4:jezik>sl</ns4:jezik></ns4:parameterLOV></ns4:parameterLOVsDTO><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25393</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>ZNAKI</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>false</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Mladi voznik</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>CK</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448104</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P247</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:parameterLOVsDTO><ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:iidLov>498565</ns4:iidLov><ns4:iidParameter>448104</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:vrednost>1</ns4:vrednost><ns4:vrstniRed>1</ns4:vrstniRed><ns4:prikazanaVrednost>da</ns4:prikazanaVrednost><ns4:jezik>sl</ns4:jezik></ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:iidLov>498566</ns4:iidLov><ns4:iidParameter>448104</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:vrednost>2</ns4:vrednost><ns4:vrstniRed>2</ns4:vrstniRed><ns4:prikazanaVrednost>ne</ns4:prikazanaVrednost><ns4:jezik>sl</ns4:jezik></ns4:parameterLOV></ns4:parameterLOVsDTO><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25394</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>ŠTEVILKE</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>false</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Starost voznika</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>SEZNAM</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448105</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P248</ns4:parameter><ns4:casS ff9 ekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25395</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>DATUM</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>true</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Datum pridobitve voznikega dovoljenja</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>DATUM_GUMB</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448106</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P249</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25431</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>ZNAKI</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>false</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Število prevoženih km na leto</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>SEZNAM</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448126</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P269</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:parameterLOVsDTO><ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:iidLov>498560</ns4:iidLov><ns4:iidParameter>448126</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:vrednost>1</ns4:vrednost><ns4:vrstniRed>1</ns4:vrstniRed><ns4:prikazanaVrednost>manj kot 10.000 km</ns4:prikazanaVrednost><ns4:jezik>sl</ns4:jezik></ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:iidLov>498561</ns4:iidLov><ns4:iidParameter>448126</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:vrednost>2</ns4:vrednost><ns4:vrstniRed>2</ns4:vrstniRed><ns4:prikazanaVrednost>med 10.000 in 20.000 km</ns4:prikazanaVrednost><ns4:jezik>sl</ns4:jezik></ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:iidLov>498569</ns4:iidLov><ns4:iidParameter>448126</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:vrednost>3</ns4:vrednost><ns4:vrstniRed>3</ns4:vrstniRed><ns4:prikazanaVrednost>med 20.000 in 30.000 km</ns4:prikazanaVrednost><ns4:jezik>sl</ns4:jezik></ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:iidLov>498570</ns4:iidLov><ns4:iidParameter>448126</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:vrednost>4</ns4:vrednost><ns4:vrstniRed>4</ns4:vrstniRed><ns4:prikazanaVrednost>med 30.000 in 40.000 km</ns4:prikazanaVrednost><ns4:jezik>sl</ns4:jezik></ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:iidLov>498571</ns4:iidLov><ns4:iidParameter>448126</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:vrednost>5</ns4:vrednost><ns4:vrstniRed>5</ns4:vrstniRed><ns4:prikazanaVrednost>veè kot 40.000 km</ns4:prikazanaVrednost><ns4:jezik>sl</ns4:jezik></ns4:parameterLOV></ns4:parameterLOVsDTO><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25432</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>ZNAKI</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>false</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Ali imate garažo</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>SEZNAM</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448127</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P270</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:parameterLOVsDTO><ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:iidLov>498572</ns4:iidLov><ns4:iidParameter>448127</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:vrednost>1</ns4:vrednost><ns4:vrstniRed>1</ns4:vrstniRed><ns4:prikazanaVrednost>da</ns4:prikazanaVrednost><ns4:jezik>sl</ns4:jezik></ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:parameterLOV><ns4:iidLov>498573</ns4:iidLov><ns4:iidParameter>448127</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:vrednost>2</ns4:vrednost><ns4:vrstniRed>2</ns4:vrstniRed><ns4:prikazanaVrednost>ne</ns4:prikazanaVrednost><ns4:jezik>sl</ns4:jezik></ns4:parameterLOV></ns4:parameterLOVsDTO><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25433</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>ZNAKI</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>true</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Ste veliko na poti</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>LOV_GUMB</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448128</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P271</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca> dbb false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25434</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>ZNAKI</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>true</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Ali potujete v tujino</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>LOV_GUMB</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448129</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P272</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25435</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>ZNAKI</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>true</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Službene poti</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>LOV_GUMB</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448130</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P273</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25436</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>ZNAKI</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>true</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Vozite 220 na uro</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>LOV_GUMB</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448131</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P274</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25437</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>ZNAKI</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>true</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Ste vedno prvi</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>LOV_GUMB</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448132</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P275</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25438</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>ZNAKI</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>true</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>To je to</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>LOV_GUMB</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448133</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P276</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:parameterPaketa><ns4:iidParPaket>25439</ns4:iidParPaket><ns4:iidPaket>441218</ns4:iidPaket><ns4:parameter><ns11:vrsta>DATOTEKA</ns11:vrsta><ns11:prostiVnos>true</ns11:prostiVnos><ns11:naziv>Kopija obstojeèe police</ns11:naziv><ns11:jezik>sl</ns11:jezik><ns11:tip>DATOTEKA</ns11:tip><ns4:iidParameter>448134</ns4:iidParameter><ns4:parameter>P277</ns4:parameter><ns4:casSekvenca>false</ns4:casSekvenca><ns4:ipo>true</ns4:ipo><ns4:kolicina>false</ns4:kolicina></ns4:parameter><ns4:zahtevanVnos>false</ns4:zahtevanVnos></ns4:parameterPaketa></ns10:vprasanja></ns10:vprasanjaZaVrstoPredmetaZavarovanja></ns6:vprasanjaZaUporabnika></input></ns8:ZapisiVprasanjaZaUporabnika></soap:Body></soap:Envelope> 0`

**response headers + response body:**

`HTTP/1.1 400 status: 400 date: Mon, 24 Sep 2018 09:00:59 GMT server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.4.16 mod_python/3.5.0- Python/2.7.5 connection: close content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>400 Bad Request</title> </head><body> <h1>Bad Request</h1> <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br /> </p> <p>Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p> </body></html> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>503 Service Unavailable</title> </head><body> <h1>Service Unavailable</h1> <p>The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.</p> <p>Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p> </body></html>`

I suspect that something goes wrong during the request when it sends the chunks of data in several requests on the same connection. Not really sure because i'm doing this for the first time.

I am using Laravel 5.6.38. Below is the code called from the application:

```
public function handle(Request $request) {   
        $opts = array(
             'http' => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
                'User-Agent' => 'PHP/SOAP',
                'Allow' => 'GET,POST',
                'Accept-Encoding:' => 'gzip, deflate, br',            
            ));`
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        
        $soapOptions = array(
            'stream_context' => $context,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            //'uri' => public_path().'/soap/storitve/app/***********Mobile/v1/***********Mobile.wsdl'
        );
  
        try {
           $server = new \SoapServer(public_path().'/soap/storitve/app/***********Mobile/v1/***********Mobile.wsdl', $soapOptions);
        //$server = new \SoapServer(null, $soapOptions);
        }
        catch (\SoapFault $sf) {
            Log::channel('soap')->info("SOAPfault: ".$sf->faultstring." (".$sf->faultcode.")");
        }
        
        $server->setObject(new Soap());
        ob_start();
        $server->handle();
        $response = ob_get_clean();


        return response($response)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8')->header('Host', env('HEADER_HOST'))->header('Allow', 'GET,POST');
    }
```

*Here is some log data that is made on each request:*

**ob_get_status(true)**

```
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'default output handler',
    'type' => 0,
    'flags' => 112,
    'level' => 0,
    'chunk_size' => 4096,
    'buffer_size' => 8192,
    'buffer_used' => 0,
  ),
)
```

**headers_list()**

```
array (
  0 => 'X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.3',
  1 => 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
)
```

**$this->_client->__getLastRequestHeaders()**

```
POST /ponudbe-storitve-3.0.0/***********/*********** HTTP/1.1
Host: **********************
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/7.2.3
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://******.***/storitve/app/***********/v1/VpisiProfilUporabnikaInPolice"
Content-Length: 263972
```

**Postman Screenshot:**
[image: postman POST request screenshot]

Sorry for the extensive post but I am having a battle with this problem for a week now and I am getting desperate so any help will be appreciated.

edit:

some additional info:

When in Postman sending the request with the Transfer-Encoding: chunked header present the logging stops at the same moment when the
**$server = new SoapServer('.......** line is called

```
[2018-09-24 14:27:57] local.INFO: initiating SoapServer  
[2018-09-24 14:27:57] local.INFO: array (
)  
[2018-09-24 14:28:02] local.DEBUG: array (
)
```

without the Transfer-Encoding the logging continues as it should. So the whole request stops at that point.

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the idea for the solution in the question below:

[Querying Exchange Web Service gives Bad Request (400) with WildFly and Apache CXF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937836/querying-exchange-web-service-gives-bad-request-400-with-wildfly-and-apache-cx)

The application that calls our Soap service is on Java Apache CXF, so all we had to do was **disable chunking** on their side and that did it.